# Elastica multiple term search not returning the correct result

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I have code with php using elastica to perform searching of products. When I select product categories as "off_furniture" and "home_furniture", the elasticsearch only return me the product with category "home_category".

Kindly throw me some lights on this. Below is what I have code:

```
$value = $_GET['prod'];
$filter_manufacturer = $_GET['man'];
$filter_price = $_GET['price'];
$cat = $_GET['cat'];

$queryString = new Elastica_Query_QueryString((string)$value);
$queryString->setDefaultOperator('OR')
->setFields(array('name'));

$category = explode("|", $cat);
$elasticaFilterBool = new Elastica_Filter_Bool();  
$filter2 = new Elastica_Filter_Term();
$filter2->setTerm('prodcat', array('off_furniture','home_furniture'));   

$elasticaFilterBool->addMust($filter2);
$query->setFilter($elasticaFilterBool);


// Create the search object and inject the client
$search = new Elastica_Search(new Elastica_Client());

// Configure and execute the search
$resultSet = $search->addIndex('products3')
                ->addType('product3')
                ->search($query);

foreach ($resultSet as $elasticaResult) {
            $result = $elasticaResult->getData();
            echo $result["name"]. "|";
    echo $result["prodcat"]. "|";
            echo $result["description"]. "|";
            echo $result["price"]. "|";
            echo $result["manufacturer"]. "|@";
        }
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? Would like to know if I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few potential issues:

1. You need to use a `terms` filter not a `term` filter. The latter only accepts one term to filter against, but you are sending two to the constructor, namely `["off_furniture", "home_furniture"]`
2. You don't need to wrap the `terms` filter in a `bool` filter if you only have one filter!
3. I can't tell from this code alone, but the mapping for the `prodcat` field needs to be `{"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}` or the tokenizer will most likely split the phrase `'home_furniture'` into two tokens `home` and `furniture` and you will not get the filters working correctly. If you are not specifying the mapping explicitly, you need to do so. Sending strings at elasticsearch will automatically apply the standard analyzer.

### Try this:

```
$prodcatFilter = new Elastica_Filter_Terms('prodcat', array('off_furniture', 'home_furniture'));
$query->setFilter($prodcatFilter);
```

Good luck!